# In dolphindb cluster mode, I add agent node and datanode node, but the datanode cannot startup

Tags: database, cluster-analysis, dolphindb

In dolphindb cluster mode, I add agent node and datanode node, but the datanode cannot startup

I start the datanode normally, but the error is: Cannot find file /home/jwu/Dolphin1.20/server/data/agent3/keys/aclPublic.key

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the keys folder first, and then restart the entire cluster. It should work without affecting the normal functions of the entire cluster.